# How can i sort hebrew in Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to sort hebrew in sql and print it in php..
I tried to do:

```
$query_skey002 = "SELECT * FROM `s_keywords` ORDER BY `name2` ASC";
```

Dont work..
I tried to use php sort function but i dont know how to sort sql array in this function
Thanks for the helpers..

Comment: Hmm, maybe you want to order binary string (seems like wrong encoding)? Try: ``SELECT * FROM `s_keywords` ORDER BY BINARY `name2` ASC``

Comment: You are welcome. :) Well main point is not make it work. I hope, you understand, why it worked. Anyway, glad that I helped you. Oh, and one more important thing: If `name2` is indexed after casting it to `BINARY` mysql won't use index.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL can sort `hebrew` text if you use the correct charset/collation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: My sql using hebrew_general_ci and my php header is windows-1255

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken and you mean how to sort based on alphabetical order, then you need to use a proper COLLATION fro your table. probably utf8-general does the job

Comment: my site using windows-1255 charset

Comment: you shall use utf8. I had this problem with Persian character as it did not allow me to do anything. You should also set_charset('utf-8') (or anything proper) before establishing any query to your database, or in other words, after connecting to db, put a line $db->set_charset('utf-8');

Answer (score 0):

I solved it..
i just changed the query to

```
$query_skey002 = "SELECT * FROM `s_keywords` ORDER BY BINARY `name2` ASC";
```

Thanks for everybody !..

Comment: _Note:_ if `name2` was indexed mysql won't use `index`. You'd really better fix encoding. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough ( or not so strange if you know that Zend is an IL company)  , a simple

`sort($query_skey002);`

in `PHP`should do for HE...